# How to know the size of the file dynamically

Tags: c++, winapi, stream, dynamic-memory-allocation

I have created preview handler for a file and when i click on that file i get  the preview of that file in preview pane and  what the scene behind is i read the file by creating a stream and and that stream i store in a buffer and then i play with the buffer contents in order to create  the preview on preview pane.

Now my question is that i want to allocate the size of that file(of which i have create dpreview handler) dynamically (using visual c++) so that i would not need to allocate the memory to the buffer manually. I mean the data is coming to the buffer using a stream and then i am storing the contents in the buffer. so actually i need to know the size of the file through that stream .(or we have to deal with the stream in knowing the size of file)

Any one have idea how to do that ??

Answer (score 0):

```
// crt_stat.c
// This program uses the _stat function to
// report information about the file named crt_stat.c.

#include <time.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main( void )
{
   struct _stat buf;
   int result;
   char timebuf[26];
   char* filename = "crt_stat.c";
   errno_t err;

   // Get data associated with "crt_stat.c": 
   result = _stat( filename, &buf );

   // Check if statistics are valid: 
   if( result != 0 )
   {
      perror( "Problem getting information" );
      switch (errno)
      {
         case ENOENT:
           printf("File %s not found.\n", filename);
           break;
         case EINVAL:
           printf("Invalid parameter to _stat.\n");
           break;
         default:
           /* Should never be reached. */
           printf("Unexpected error in _stat.\n");
      }
   }
   else
   {
      // Output some of the statistics: 
      printf( "File size     : %ld\n", buf.st_size );
      printf( "Drive         : %c:\n", buf.st_dev + 'A' );
      err = ctime_s(timebuf, 26, &buf.st_mtime);
      if (err)
      {
         printf("Invalid arguments to ctime_s.");
         exit(1);
      }
      printf( "Time modified : %s", timebuf );
   }
}
```

Comment: For Windows, `GetFileSize` is probably more appropriate.  But all of the Windows solutions will return a value slightly too large for files opened in text mode.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution would be something like:

```
std::vector<char> data( (std::istreambuf_iterator<char>( file )),
                        (std::istreambuf_iterator<char>()) );
```

This will create a vector with exactly the number of bytes you
read.  This isn't optimal from a performance point of view:
there will be reallocations and copies, because the vector can't
know how much to allocate in advance.  But it's sufficient for
most uses.  (The reallocations and copies generally take less
time than the actual reading.)

If you really want to pre-allocate, there is no truly portable
solution.  In fact, on many systems, including Windows, there is
*no* way of knowing in advance how many `char` you will be able
to read from a file opened in text mode.  In practice, however,
seeking to the end, then converting the results of
`istream::tellg()` to a sufficiently large integral type will
work under both Windows and Unix systems, giving the exact
results under Unix, and a value typically a little too large
(but possibly up to twice the actual size) under Windows.  And
this is about as close as you can come.  (Note that technically,
you're even guaranteed that the results of `istream::tellg` is
even convertible to an integral type, or if it is, that the
results aren't some magic cookie.  In practice, however, it will
work under Windows and Unix, although probably not on
a mainframe.)

Otherwise, you can use the system specific function
`GetFileSize` (or `stat` under Unix), with the same
restrictions: the Unix results will be exact, those under
Windows will be slightly larger than necessary if you're opening
the file in text mode.

Answer (score 0):

I have done it just used a new operator . before i was using the stack which is has limit for size and my file (which was to be stored in the buffer had size of the order of 4mb) so stack was overflowing i made its solution by doing as below-

```
const int Size=5348928;
char* Buffer = new char[Size + 1];
```

instead of doing like this-

```
char buffer[5348928]; //it will give stack over flow because the size of stack is limited
```

and it works fine.

Comment: Please tell me you aren't hardcoding the size of the file in your code.

Comment: sorry...Please explain your question?? yes i am using this file size which is of the order of 4-5mb. actually i am storing a stream in side this buffer (which is of big size so char buffer[5348928]; was not working )

Comment: What happens if the size of the file changes? What if it gets bigger than this size? If it gets smaller, why allocate so much? In fact, I despair. Words cannot describe how bad this is.

Comment: @Neil The 1 solution is to allocate big size to "size" variable but thats not so good could you please give me some suggestion???and  thanks for your care to my question but could you pleasse give me the idea how i can declare it dynamically actually i want the buffer to allocate its size dynamically according to its need (not like as i do..It just for the moment in my program but won't work for every program).Please give me suggestion to do that

Comment: Look at the example code on this page, it shows how to find the size of a file and read it into memory. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/tellg/

Comment: @thaks Neil but here i n this case we know the name of the file which is "test.txt" but in my case i even don't know the name of the file which to be clicked to generate a stream.(i think you still not uderstood my problem). I am creating a preview handler so ahen i click the file in window explorer(suppose the fileis .jpeg)then i should get its preview in preview pane. and it should work for every file(i mean every .jpeg file-whose size i don't know. name could be shekhar.jpeg or Neil.jpeg) we don't know the name of file. i just click on it and create a stream and  store in buffer. understod

Comment: still do you have any solution ?? (and one more thing i am working in visual c++)

Comment: You don't have to pass a constant to the stream constructor. You can pass your own string. If it is std::string, use c_str method.